# how to find an element in mammoth module object in python

Tags: python, mammoth

```
import mammoth

Docx = open(r'D:\python\temp\sampletable.docx', 'rb')

document = mammoth.convert_to_html(Docx)
```

E.g. I want to find <table> element in document object